# How does the output differ?

Tags: c, unix

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("If I had more time, \n");
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "I would have written you a shorter letter.\n", 43); 
    return 0;
}
```

how does the output differ depending on whether standard output is redirected to a terminal or to a disk file?

Comment: Uh, well, if the output is redirected to a terminal it will be redirected to a terminal, and if it's redirected to a file on disk it will be redirected to a file on disk. I think that's quite obvious.

Comment: Why you have not included `unistd.h`?

Comment: Anything wrong with `FILE* f = fopen("myfile.txt", "a"); fprintf(f, "I would have written you a shorter letter.\n");` ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume the question is "why is the output different when printed to a terminal than to a regular file?".  When stdout is a tty, it is typically line buffered, so the printf invokes write because your output includes a newline.  When the output is a regular file, the output is block buffered, so the c stdio library delays the write.  In that case, the data written via printf is not written until after main returns, so that data appears in the output after the data you have written via `write`.

Answer (score 1):

there may be a slight difference with flush-ing. If the program terminates (prematurly) before closing the filedescriptor, the file may not contain all output, while output to stdout is flushed with the newline.

Answer (score 0):

It should not differ. Both the statements (printf as well as write) are writing to the stdout and hence to the terminal. If you redirect it to a disk file, it will be same only.